# Two class classification problem -- only negative labels corrupted

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to train a deep learning model to solve a two class classification problem. My positive data are perfectly clean, whereas in negative data, roughly 10% of the label are corrupted(i.e. 10% of the labels for negative samples are 1, rather than 0). The size of training data for both class is relatively big, with millions of samples. I know there are methods for label corruption problems, but I would like to know if there are methods to try for my specific setting: labels are corrupted for only one class. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried unsupervised learning, to see how it matches with your actual labels?

Comment: @user2974951 It's a text classification problem, I am trying to use Bert, which is self-supervisedly pretrained